# Find $\frac{a}{c}$ for an isosceles triangle if $\frac{r}{R}=k$

Tags: geometry, triangles

Let $c$ be the length of the base of an isosceles triangle, $a$ the length of the legs, $R$ the radius of the circumscribed circle and $r$ the radius of the incircle of the triangle.

> Find $\frac{a}{c}$ if $\frac{r}{R}=k$

I've done:
\begin{align}
S&=\frac{abc}{4R}\\
S&=pr\\
\frac{a^2c}{4R}&=\frac{2a+c}{2}r
\end{align}
And don't know how to continue.

Comment: What are $a$, $b$, $c$, $r$, $R$, $k$, $S$, $p$? Please add some context, or a picture

Comment: If a and b are equal then $\dfrac{a}{b}=1$.Is a and b have different lenghts.

Comment: What is c and a?

Comment: c is the length of the base, a is the length of the legs, R is the radius of the circumscribed circle and r is the radius of the incircle

Comment: Where did the circle come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean $a=b$.
Thus, $2a>c$ or $\frac{a}{c}>\frac{1}{2}$ and
$$k=\frac{r}{R}=\frac{\frac{2S}{a+b+c}}{\frac{abc}{4S}}=\frac{16S^2}{2abc(a+b+c)}=$$
$$=\frac{(a+b-c)(a+c-b)(b+c-a)}{2abc}=\frac{(2a-c)c^2}{2a^2c}=\frac{\frac{2a}{c}-1}{\frac{2a^2}{c^2}}.$$
Hence,
$$\frac{2ka^2}{c^2}-\frac{2a}{c}+1=0,$$
which gives
$$\frac{a}{c}=\frac{1\pm\sqrt{1-2k}}{2k}.$$

Answer (score 0):

We know that $r=4R\sin{(\dfrac{A}{2})} \sin{(\dfrac{B}{2})} \sin{(\dfrac{C}{2})}.$ where A, B and C are the angles of the triangles.
And $\dfrac{a}{c}=\tan{A}$, where A is the equal angles or base angles which can be proofed using sine rule.

Now $\frac{r}{R}=k=8\sin{(\dfrac{A}{2})}\cos{(\dfrac{A}{2})}$, 
$\therefore k=4\sin{A}$.
Now you should express $\sin{A}$in terms of $\tan{A}$, and then find the values of $\tan{A}$ in terms of k and it is done.